# Telling Linux kernel to apply appletouch driver instead of usbmouse driver to touchpad

Tags: kernel-modules, mouse

I'm currently running Linux on an old macbook. It's too old for the modern apple touchpad driver so I have to use the old appletouch driver. Whenever I boot the computer the kernel uses the usbmouse driver for the touchpad, so I have to invoke

```
rmmod usbmouse
rmmod appletouch
modprobe appletouch
modprobe usbmouse
```

in order to get the touchpad working and allow external usb mice. I currently just have a script I run manually on startup to fix the mouse for me, but I was wondering if there was some configuration I could modify to have this happen automatically for me?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here (How To: Start a program or script on boot)](https://help.skysilk.com/support/solutions/articles/9000162390--basic-how-to-start-a-program-or-script-on-linux-automatically-on-boot-with-systemd#How-to-start-a-program-on-Linux-automatically-on-boot)

Summary: Create an executable bash script, then create a systemd service (detailed in the article above) that executes the script on startup.

Edit: I apparently don't know how to use a keyboard. (Fixed typos)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).